# cast in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I need help with this query:

```
 $qb->innerJoin(
            AdminAccount::class,
            'aa',
            Join::WITH,
            'gafl.key = :adminAccKeyName and gafl.oldValue = aa.id::varchar'
        );
        $qb->setParameter('adminAccKeyName', 'admin_account_id');
        $qb->setParameter('aaId', 'admin_account_id');
```

I use `getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();`

```
"errorMessage": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 540: Error: Expected end of string, got ':'",
```

If I try to use cast I have:

```
"errorMessage": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 498: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'"
```

Нow can I compare fields of different formats?

I tried to debug in query console, if i use `INNER JOIN admin_accounts a2_ ON (g0_.key = 'admin_account_id' AND cast(g0_.old_value as INT) = a2_.id)` everything is working

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It helps to format your code using [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to make your question more readable